# How can I create an FTP user with access to my CentOS Virtual Server?

Tags: centos, ftp

I have a virtual server running CentOS, and need to create an FTP user to give to a client so they can upload some files to me.

Any idea how I go about this, and how I only give them access to upload from one folder? (I don't care what folder, as long as they do not get access to my other files.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the basics

Create a local user account for your client give it a password and home directory etc.

Install vsftpd

```
yum install vsftpd
```

Edit

> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
xferlog_file=YES
local_umask=022
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
```

save the file and exit then restart vsftpd

```
/sbin/service vsftpd restart
```

and ensure it runs when the system starts

```
/sbin/chkconfig vsftpd on
```

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`

ensure that there is an entry for `IPTABLES_MODULES` which amongst other things contains `ip_conntrack_ftp` e.g.

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp"
```

Then modify the firewall

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

edit /etc/sysconfig/iptables

After the line

`:RH-Firewall-1-Input - [0:0]` or similar ( the [0:0] may be different) add

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

save the file and exit then restart the firewall

```
/sbin/service iptables restart
```

You sould be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up an SFTP server with OpenSSH and a chrooted home directory for your user(s).  Benefits: key pair authentication (so you can disable password authentication), you don't need (or they don't need) to open any additional ports beyond TCP 22, end-to-end encryption, and with a chrooted home directory, they're "jailed" within their chrooted home directory only and have no access outside of that directory.